# stream-chat-react causing invalid hook call error

Tags: reactjs, mern

Chat component causing
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

thx for helping

```
import React from 'react';
import {StreamChat} from 'stream-chat';
import {Chat} from 'stream-chat-react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

import {ChannelListContainer, ChannelContainer} from './components';

const apiKey = "up8qhqy7fp8u";
const client = StreamChat.getInstance(apiKey);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app__wrapper">
        <Chat client={client} theme="team light"> //chat causing "Invalid hook call" error
            <ChannelListContainer 

            />
            <ChannelContainer 

            />
        </Chat>
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: btw react and reactDom both same versions

Answer (score 0):

OK apparently there was duplicate reacts in my project.
this solved my issue :
https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react